# In XSLT, how do you show the value of a child node depending of the value of another child node

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use XSLT to transform one XML document into another XML document.

The original XML is formatted like so;

```
<NodeList>
    <Node>
      <Type>Commercial</Type>
      <ContactDetail>
        <Name>The Shop</Name>
        <Line01>1 The Lane</Line01>
        <Line02></Line02>
        <Line03>London</Line03>
        <PostCode>SW11AA</PostCode>
        <TelMobile>07777123456</TelMobile>
      </ContactDetail>
    </Node>
    <Node>
      <Type>Municiple</Type>
      <ContactDetail>
        <Name>Some place</Name>
        <Line01>1 Hub Lane</Line01>
        <Line02>PLYMOUTH</Line02>
        <Line03>DEVON</Line03>
        <Line04></Line04>
        <PostCode>PL62BB<</PostCode>
        <TelMobile>01234567890</TelMobile>
      </ContactDetail>
    </Node>
<NodeList>
```

And I need to be able to print the contact details of NodeList/Node[Type='Commercial'] but for the life of me, I can not find the correct way of doing this.

I thought something along the lines of;

```
<xsl:value-of select="NodeList/Node/[Type='Commercial"]/ContactDetails/Name" />
```

But of course "ContactDetails" isn't a child of "Type".

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. Remove the slash between Node and your condition. That way you are selecting the Node element that matches the condition in the brackets.

`NodeList/Node[Type="Commercial"]/ContactDetail/Name`

Also, the condition was checking for 'Commercial", which will give you an error from the quotes, and the end of the xpath was looking for ContactDetails instead of ContactDetail, which is what your example had. Both of those are corrected in the above query.

Comment: Thank you, that had been driving me crazy for too long. The extra slash I had before the condition was a typo in the question only but I had been putting "ContactDetails" in the code by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is `NodeList/Node[Type='Commercial']/ContactDetails/Name`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access repeated nodes, you can use [`xsl:key`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key), for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:key name="nodeTypeKey" match="Node" use="Type" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="addressToUse" 
                    select="key('nodeTypeKey', 'Commercial')/ContactDetail">
      </xsl:variable>
      <Name><xsl:value-of select="$addressToUse/Name"/></Name>
      <Tel><xsl:value-of select="$addressToUse/TelMobile"/></Tel>
      <!-- etc -->
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```